# How to get the basic example Shiny app working?

Tags: r, shiny

I can't make the first example of the first Shiny Tutorial to work.... on windows 10, R 3.6.1

I followed : https://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/written-tutorial/lesson1/

I get some part of the app : title / input field... no CSS, not working... only the title as shown below : :-(

[image]

Comment: Would you include the complete code you used to generate this app? Was it `runExample('01_hello')`? Does the same happens if you open it in browser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was coming from one special caracter in my username !

My usernmae "stéphane" was transformed by R into "stiphane"... was led to a wrong path name for the shiny files...

Creating another Windows user without any accentuated caracter wolved the problem...